# Set the default value to reactive control if nothing is entered

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have reactive form in my Angular app with number inputs:

```
initForm() {
  this.form = this.fb.group(
    coffee: ['0', [
      Validators.min(0)
    ]],
    tea: ['0', [
      Validators.min(0)
    ]],
}
```

Every input have '0' as value when they init, but user can remove value and save form. I want set '0' to all controls without values, when user save form. How can i do this correctly?

Comment: you can  use valueChanges event on corresponding control and set default value if the filed is empty

Comment: @AbineshDevadas really, thanks. Why I did not immediately think about it... )

Answer (score 1):

```
save(): void {
    const controlNames = Object.keys(this.form.controls);
    for (const name of controlNames) {
        if (this.form.get(name) && !this.form.get(name).value) {
            this.form.get(name).setValue('0')
        }
    }
    ...remaining save logic elided since it's out of scope of the question
}
```